# Marking the High of Previous Reds Whenever the High is Greater Than the one After it

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Complex title sorry, basically, I'm trying to mark (starting from last weeks weekly if its red or the most recent red weekly candle that isn't this week) the high of weekly red candles in a sort of stairstep fashion from right to left.

I have no idea how to go about doing this at the moment and could use the help, so far all I have is a script that marks every single high of every red starting from the most recent one (besides the current week) and I don't think I'm getting anywhere with it.

Comment: a drawing could be usefull...